# SQL - Why does AS work with UNION but not JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, union

I've recently been picking up SQL and doing exercises from SQL-EX. One thing I am trying to wrap my head around and haven't been able to find information on is the AS statement combined with UNION.

As per the following, I am able to store my data "AS" a after doing a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MODEL, PRICE FROM PC
UNION
SELECT MODEL, PRICE FROM LAPTOP
UNION
SELECT MODEL, PRICE FROM PRINTER) AS A
WHERE A.MODEL IN (SELECT MODEL FROM PRODUCT WHERE MAKER = 'B')
```

However, why isn't the following possible? Does JOIN not create a dataset I can also name "AS" a?

```
Select distinct maker from (SELECT *
FROM Product INNER JOIN 
 PC ON PC.model = Product.model) as a
where a.speed > 450
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the context of assigning an alias to a table (or view) reference, the **`AS`** keyword *illegal* in some databases (e.g. Oracle), and is entirely *optional* in most other databases (MySQL, SQL Server, et al.)  My personal preference is to *never* use the `AS` keyword with an alias for a table reference, and to *always* include the `AS` keyword for a column alias (Even though it's optional there as well, I think including it makes it more intentionally clear that we mean a column alias, and it's not just a "missing comma" between two expressions in the SELECT list.)

Comment: I suspect the "isn't the following possible" question is *not* related to the `AS` keyword, but is due to the inline view query returning *duplicate* column names... two columns named `model`. The exact error message is going to differ between databases, but would likely include text including something along the lines of "duplicate column name". But, we're really just guessing, with no indication given *what* RDBMS is being used (Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, Teradata, etc.) and without any indication of the error message returned by the database.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `SELECT * FROM`. You must name the columns which you want to refer to later.

The following SQL should do the trick (untested):

```
Select distinct a.maker from (SELECT speed, maker
FROM Product INNER JOIN 
PC ON PC.model = Product.model) a
where a.speed > 450;
```

Comment: it seems like the inline view would need to return a column named `maker`. I don't see how this would work otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The column `a.speed` must be there to make the `WHERE` clause work and the column `maker` must be there to be able to select from it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: And this relies on the column `speed` appearing in only one of the referenced tables, and the column `maker` appearing in only one of the tables. If the column `maker` appears in both tables for example, this statement would throw an "ambiguous column" error, because the column references aren't qualified.

Answer (score 0):

This question asks why something isn't possible.  I suspect the question is really "why is the database returning this particular error?".

If this isn't for Oracle, then the `AS` keyword isn't the issue. (Oracle disallows the `AS` keyword for table aliases. For other databases, the `AS` keyword is optional, and not required.)

If this question is reporting that the database is returning an error, I suspect it's returning a "duplicate column name" error, due to the `SELECT *` in the inline view. The reason that's a problem is that it's returning *two* columns named `model`, one from PC and one from Product. And it's not valid to return two columns of the same name in a view (inline or stored.)  This would be illegal:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ( SELECT pc.model
              , pr.model
           FROM ...
       ) v
```

Because the inline view v would be attempting to return two columns named `model`.

But something like this should be valid (assuming `maker` is a column in `Product` and `speed` is a column in `PC`, and both tables contain a column named `model`.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.maker
   FROM ( SELECT pr.maker
               , pc.speed
               , pr.model 
               , pc.model AS pc_model
            FROM Product pr
            JOIN PC pc 
              ON pc.model = pr.model
        ) a
  WHERE a.speed > 450
```

Note that returning the `model` column is not required. That is shown just to demonstrate how we would assign a different column name to an expression, so that the inline view query doesn't return duplicate column names.

If this query is giving problems, test the inline view query separately. (The SELECT between the parens should be a valid statement that can be executed separately.)

I strongly recommend you *qualify* all column references in the query, as shown in the above example, to avoid ambiguous column errors.